# What's the right way to keep an Android Xamarin app syncing with a webservice in background?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'd like to check a webservice every hour and update a SQLite database.

I've implemented this using a System.Timer and it kind of works, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
/* 
... code
*/

   var timerSync = new Timer(60 * 60 * 1000);
   timerNotify.Elapsed += (sender, e) => HandleTimerSync();
   timerNotify.Start();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this is an interesting blog for you? https://blog.xamarin.com/performing-background-data-refresh-for-android/

Comment: Please refer to [Intelligent Job-Scheduling](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html).